# Dynamic Validation Messages Using Yup and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yup

I am trying to create some custom error messages with Yup to determine if the user's email address is in use.

I have created the following promise to try and catch a server communication error:

```js
.test(
{
    name: 'Email Check',
    test: value => {
        if (value.includes("@")) {
            return new Promise<yup.ValidationError>((resolve, reject) => {
                let client = new RegistrationApi();
                client.emailCheck(value,
                    x => x ? resolve(undefined) : resolve(new yup.ValidationError("E-mail address already used", value, "")),
                    () =>resolve(new yup.ValidationError("Failed to contact server", value, "")),
                    undefined);
            });
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}),
```

Returning the validation errors doesn't result in any error message being displayed. What am I doing wrong? I have tried to use the createError method which seems to be details in examples, but it doesn't seem to exist in this context.

Comment: alternate solution but see if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809526/handling-errors-from-api-with-formik/56813302#56813302

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also trying something similar.

Answer (score 3):

```
    /* An example of a dynamic error message for Required, depending on other vars */
    title: yup.string().nullable().test('test-titleRequired', '',  function (value, context) {
        if (!value || !value.trim().length) {
            if (context.parent.someOtherField === 'Special Value') {
                return this.createError({ message: 'Message Version 1' });
            } else {
                return this.createError({ message: 'Message Version 2' });
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }),
```

Important Note: **must** use the `function` syntax (not arrows `=>`)

Comment: It can actually do this with an arrow function; you just have to pass in `testContext` in addition to `value`, and call `testContext.createError`.

Comment: not with Typescript

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code, you will want to **`reject`** your Promise and not `resolve` it.

generally;
you need to return a promise to the [validation function](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedvalidatevalue-any-options-object-promiseany-validationerror) of your yup schema. Or you can write a [specific async test](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema).

Answer (score 0):

`createError` needs to be used inside of a function declaration for the test method. You are currently using an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in separate helper. for ex it can be a util or hook, where you are checking something manually and set/reset error.

```
if (isNotValid) {
  await form.setError('myError', {
    type: 'manual',
    message: mealErrorMsg,
  });
} else {
  await form.clearErrors('myError');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to correct the record - you *can* use `createError` with arrow syntax -

```
// test that content doesn't exceed a certain length, for example.
.test('content', 'Content maximum exceeded - 1000 character max.', (value: string, testContext: Yup.TestContext) => {
            const characters = value.text.length
            if (characters > 1000) {
                return testContext.createError({
                    message: `Currently at ${characters} characters`,
                    path: 'content',
                })
            }
            return true
        })
```