# How to set dynamic error messages in Yup async validation?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying async validation in Formik using Yup's `.test()` method and need to set the error message that I get from the API. Error messages are going to be different based on some conditions in backend.

Tried few solutions mentioned here
https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/222 and [Dynamic Validation Messages Using Yup and Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154861/dynamic-validation-messages-using-yup-and-typescript)

But Yup is throwing the default error message given in `test()`.

Documentation says that

> All tests must provide a name, an error message and a validation function that must return true or false or a ValidationError. To make a test async return a promise that resolves true or false or a ValidationError.

I am resolving a new ValidationError with the error message but still, it throws the default error.

Here is the code.

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().test(
    "email_async_validation",
    "Email Validation Error", // YUP always throws this error
    value => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        emailValidationApi(value)
          .then(res => {
            const { message } = res.data; // I want this error message to be shown in form.
            resolve(new Yup.ValidationError(message));
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      });
    }
  )
});
```

Comment: Where is `resolve` coming from? it's an unknown import

Comment: it should be available from ```this``` so something like ```this.resolve```

Comment: Is it possible to have this for multiple field's error messages...e.g. field 1 with test returning "Field 1 is invalid" and field 2 with test returning "Field 2 is invalid"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it working using the `function` syntax instead of arrow function for validation function.

Doc says:

> test functions are called with a special context, or `this` value, that
> exposes some useful metadata and functions. Note that to use `this`
> context, the test function must be a function expression `(function test(value) {})`, not an arrow function, since arrow functions have
> lexical context.

Here is the working code.

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email("Not a valid email")
    .required("Required")
    .test("email_async_validation", "Email Validation Error", function (value) { // Use function
      return emailValidationApi(value)
        .then((res) => {
          const message = res;
          console.log("API Response:", message);
          return this.createError({ message: message });
          // return Promise.resolve(this.createError({ message: message })); // This also works
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Note that accessing `createError` is also possible with arrow syntax, by passing in `testContext` along with `value`, then using `testContext.createError()`.

Comment: I'm just curious, the "Email Validation Error" is the message, but how/ what is it used for? Is it just a readability thing, unfortunately I cannot find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you're almost correct.You just need to use the following:

```
resolve(this.createError({ message: message }));
```

Let me know if it still doesn't work ya

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue and what I missed is that it's not enough to just call `createError` but you also have to return the result of it from your validation function.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to do this with arrow function as well.

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
 email: Yup.string()
  .email("Not a valid email")
  .required("Required")
  .test("email_async_validation", "Email Validation Error", (value, {createError}) { 
    return emailValidationApi(value)
      .then((res) => {
        const message = res;
        console.log("API Response:", message);
        return createError({ message: message });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass second parameter, as we generally pass it as a error message instead create your own custom message using "createError" and return it on your condition.

```
import * as yup from "yup";

const InitiateRefundSchema = yup.object().shape({
  amountPaid: yup.number(),
  refundAmount: yup
    .number()
    .test("test-compare a few values", function (value) {
      let value1 = this.resolve(yup.ref("amountPaid"));
      let value2 = this.resolve(yup.ref("refundAmount"));
      if (value1 < value2) {
        return this.createError({
          message: `refund amount cannot be greater than paid amount '${value1}'`,
          path: "refundAmount", // Fieldname
        });
      } else return true;
    }),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With Internatilization ('vue-i18n') and Yup ('yup') options you could use as:

```
const fullname = yup.string().required(this.$t('validate.required')).min(8, this.$t('validate.min', {min: '8'}))
```

So with this line below, the text error message will be changed as the locale option change.

```
this.$t('validate.min')
```

pt.ts

```js
    validation: {
        required: 'Esse campo é obrigatório',
        size_min: 'Deve no minimo {min} caracteres',
    }
```

en.ts

```js
    validation: {
        required: 'Required please',
        size_min: 'Please only {min} caracteres',
    }
```